# Python IDLE code gives error upon installation of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Python 3.6.0 (32-bit) is installed on my Windows 10 machine (64-bit).
This is office machine and Python is installed by IT team.
I'm using IDLE to run code.
Without installing matplotlib, the code runs fine.
However, as soon as matplotlib is installed, even the existing code does not run.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\saurabh.gupta1\lib\pathlib.py", line 1231, in mkdir
        self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
      File "C:\Users\saurabh.gupta1\lib\pathlib.py", line 388, in wrapped
        return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'K:\\.matplotlib'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\saurabh.gupta1\lib\pathlib.py", line 1231, in mkdir
        self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
      File "C:\Users\saurabh.gupta1\lib\pathlib.py", line 388, in wrapped
        return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'K:\\'
```

It is looking for K: drive which does not exist. Not sure why its doing so!

Tried reducing the code to a minimal in my .py file.
It gives above error even with only 1 statement in the .py file e.g.

```
    check.py with following line of code:
    import matplotlib
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib with the following commands:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

If this doesn't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling python.
I see that python has been installed by your IT team so, try this [method](https://copdips.com/2018/06/install-python-on-windows-with-powershell-without-administrator-privileges.html) if you don't have the password.

Try installing the 64-bit version because the 32-bit one might have some problems.

Lastly, if none of this works, try installing anaconda(or miniconda) and make a virtual environment. Anaconda was made especially for installing such libraries with ease and even optimizes your library for best performance.

These are my 2 cents and I hope they help you out :)

Comment: ok thanks. let me reach out to IT to see if they can help install python 64-bit version.

Comment: Ok. If this still doesn't work, ask them to install anaconda